# How can I prevent my query from throwing this error about a duplicate column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a query that returns only one row for a certain combination of table data.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.aaa_id ORDER BY s.Stats_ID DESC) AS Rank   
     FROM 
         dev.dbo.Stats s
     INNER JOIN 
         dev.dbo.Admin_X m ON s.main_id = m.main_id
     INNER JOIN 
         dev.dbo.Mod_Admin a ON s.aaa_id = a.aaa_id
     WHERE 
         m.early_reg_FLAG = 1 OR a.early_reg = 'Y'
    ) AA 
WHERE 
    Rank =1
```

But I keep getting this error:

> The column 'main_id' was specified multiple times for 'AA'.

I know I am using a column called `main_id` twice, but they are from different tables.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: CTE is an instantiated VIEW, same so the rule that a VIEW all columns have to be with unique name applies to a CTE. Avoid using * in the CTE and give explicit list of the columns that you need

Comment: @LuisLL Oh ok, so my use of `SELECT *` is my problem here?  thank you!

Comment: The problem is in the `SELECT *` in the subquery, you have twice main_id, one from dev.dbo.Stat table and the other one from dev.dbo.Admin_X table. Do not use SELECT *

Comment: This is just one reason why being explicit with your columns in the `SELECT` is good advice. Get into the *good* habit of doing it

Comment: FYI, @LuisLL , the above isn't a Common Table Expression (CTE), it's a Derived Table. They are similar, but not the same and do have slightly different behaviour.

Comment: @Larnu, you are right, it's a derived table and not a CTE, and you are right again that they have (real)  different behaviour.

Comment: `JOIN USING` would solve this issue but it's not [yet] supported by SQL Server. `FETCH NEXT <n> ROWS WITH TIES` would also solve this problem but alas... it's not supported either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the expense of a second reference to each table, you can try just selecting the primary keys in the subselect and then re-retrieving the data in the outer select:

```
SELECT s.*, m.*, a.*, AA.Rank 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         s.Stats_id, m.Admin_X_id, a.Mod_Admin_id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.aaa_id ORDER BY s.Stats_ID DESC) AS Rank
     FROM
         dev.dbo.Stats s
     INNER JOIN
         dev.dbo.Admin_X m ON s.Stats_id = m.Stats_id
     INNER JOIN
         dev.dbo.Mod_Admin a ON s.aaa_id = a.aaa_id
     WHERE
         m.early_reg_FLAG = 1 OR a.early_reg = 'Y'
    ) AA 
INNER JOIN
    dev.dbo.Stats s ON AA.Stats_id = s.Stats_id
INNER JOIN
    dev.dbo.Admin_X m ON AA.Admin_X_id = m.Admin_X_id
INNER JOIN
    dev.dbo.Mod_Admin a ON AA.Mod_Admin_id = a.Mod_Admin_id
WHERE
    AA.Rank = 1
```

Here, I've used `Stats_id`, `Admin_X_id`, and `Mod_Admin_id` as placeholders for the primary keys of the respective tables.

If either of the inner joins are many-to-1 (and not many-to-0/1), you may be able to eliminate that table reference from the inner subquery. (The join to `Mod_Admin` might qualify.)